# hiding data series points while showing others with flot

Tags: javascript, flot

I wanted to plot 2 data series.

The first one is a dynamic series of events which has time and height (water level).

The second is a maximum height from t=0 till indef.

I want the first data series with points and the second without points (since it is just a warning line).

So far i tried the following:

```
pl_data[0].data = plot_data;
pl_data[1].data = plot_maxHeightCoords;
var pl_options = {   series: {
                    lines: { show: true },
                    points: { show:[true,false] }
                    }
};
$.plot("#placeholder_flot", pl_data, pl_options);
```

and this:

```
pl_options.points:[true,false];
```

This however wont work. It worked for colors so i figured it should for points too.

I read the documentation but could not find a hint to fix this.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure I'm following your question but I think you want to configure each series separately and not within your plot `options`.

If the objects are already created:

```
pl_data[0].data = plot_data;
pl_data[1].data = plot_maxHeightCoords;
pl_data[0].points = {};
pl_data[0].points.show = true;
pl_data[1].points = {};
pl_data[1].points.show = false;
```

Or recreate the data object:

```
var pl_data = [ {data: plot_data, points: {show: true}, lines: {show: true}},
                {data: plot_maxHeightCoords, points: {show: false}, lines: {show: true}} ];

$.plot("#placeholder_flot", pl_data, {});
```

This is discussed under the [data format section](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#data-format) of the documentation.